# TensorRT installation in ubuntu shows Invalid Debian format

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, tensorrt

```
dpkg-deb: error: 'nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.3-cuda-11.8_1.0-1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.3-cuda-11.8_1.0-1_amd64.deb (--install):
dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.3-cuda-11.8_1.0-1_amd64.deb
```

TensorRT installation in ubuntu20.04 shows this error

I downloaded the debian file with "wget" command from nvidia official website and followed same steps of installation as mention in there docs . But not able to install , error is " invalid debian formate"